# How to bind values to dynamic controls in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am loading form controls dynamically by making 2 api calls. First api to get form control's list and second api to get data for the controls loaded previously.
First half works fine and i am able to load controls dynamically,

schema:

```
[{ id: 1, input: 'TextBox'},
 { id: 2, input: 'TextArea'}]
```

code:

```
fields.map((type: any, i: any) => {
  switch (type.input) {
   case 'TextBox':
   return (<input type="text" id={type.id}> />)
   case 'TextArea':
   return (<textarea itemType="text" id={type.id}> />)}});
```

Above code works fine and I am able to create form controls.

Next part is binding value to the dynamic controls, I make another API call to get data and I should map id field and bind data

schema:

```
[{ id: 1, value: 'testTextBox'},
 { id: 2, value: 'testTextArea'}]
```

How can I bind data to the controls now?
I have tried using state, but not able to achieve that. 
or i can update first schema and add value key to it after i get second api response
something like below,

```
 fields = [{ id: 1, input: 'TextBox', value: 'testTextBox'},
     { id: 2, input: 'TextArea', value: 'testTextArea'}]
```

Please suggest how to loop and add value key to fields array?

Comment: It will be better if you create controls on the response of second API.

Comment: i cannot change the api... i can only create some temp schema

Comment: But you can definitely change the formation of form controls.

Comment: Please suggest how to add new key to fields array?

Comment: fields = [{ id: 1, input: 'TextBox'},
 { id: 2, input: 'TextArea'}]

Comment: should be, fields = [{ id: 1, input: 'TextBox', value: 'testTextBox'},
     { id: 2, input: 'TextArea', value: 'testTextArea'}]

Comment: Will the length of the response in both the APIs will remain same??

Comment: no it will not be same, i have to match id field and update the control

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204778/discussion-between-mayank-bansal-and-apps).

Answer (score 0):

use:
    setState({})

create the controls binded to state as:

```
(<input type="text" id={type.id}> value={this.state.id}/>)
```

upon receiving the values set it in the state as:

```
this.setState({id: value});
```

Comment: i cannot use setState({id: value}) since controls are dynamic , i will generate 10 input fields dynamically and it will bind same value to all input fields because  value={this.state.id} is same for all 10 input fields